# In R, when summary() and emmeans() give different results, which one should I trust?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model

I want to compare scores in the "control" condition to the "high" condition and to the "low" condition. The `summary()` and the `emmeans()` functions give different significance results for the "high" vs "control" contrast: the "high" vs "control" contrast is significant in the result given by `summary()` but not `emmeans()`.
Why do they give different results? Which one should I trust?

Here is the [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qE7ndNNCmnyRkb0hqcXTlL52pFtgjBZe/view?usp=sharing).

Here is code I ran to get the results:

```
# load library
library(tidyverse)
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)

# read in data
df.mod <- df.csv

# set contrasts to compare "high" to "control", and compare "low" to "control" using summary()
highVScontrol <- c(-1/2, 1/2, 0)
lowVScontrol <- c(-1/2, 0, 1/2)
contrasts(df.mod$condition) <- cbind(highVScontrol, lowVScontrol)

# fit model
mod <- lmer(score ~ condition + (1|subject), data = df.mod, REML = 
FALSE)
summary(mod)

#########
# Output 
# Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
# lmerModLmerTest]
# Formula: score ~ condition + (1 | subject)
# Data: df.mod
# 
# AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
# 283.0    295.5   -136.5    273.0       85 
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
# Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -3.09796 -0.51784  0.06943  0.64971  2.46609 
# 
# Random effects:
# Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
# subject  (Intercept) 0.2618   0.5116  
# Residual             1.0024   1.0012  
# Number of obs: 90, groups:  subject, 30
# 
# Fixed effects:
# Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)             -1.0650     0.1409 30.0000  -7.557    2e-08 ***
# conditionhighVScontrol   0.5342     0.2985 60.0000   1.790   0.0786 .  
# conditionlowVScontrol    0.6646     0.2985 60.0000   2.226   0.0298 *  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
# (Intr) cndtnhVS
# cndtnhghVSc  0.000         
# cndtnlwVScn  0.000 -0.500  
#########

# comparison using emmeans()
emmeans(mod, list(pairwise ~ condition), adjust = "holm")

#########
# Output
# $`emmeans of condition`
# condition emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
# high      -1.332 0.209 85.8   -1.747  -0.9170
# control   -0.466 0.209 85.8   -0.881  -0.0506
# low       -1.397 0.209 85.8   -1.812  -0.9822
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 
# 
# $`pairwise differences of condition`
# contrast       estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
# high - control  -0.8664 0.263 62.1 -3.295  0.0033 
# high - low       0.0652 0.263 62.1  0.248  0.8050 
# control - low    0.9316 0.263 62.1  3.543  0.0023 
# 
# P value adjustment: holm method for 3 tests 
#######
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be something off about your contrast coding. This is not something I am terribly familiar with, so I ran the model without the contrast coding, and instead recoded condition into numerical values as such (note I called your dataset test):

```
test <- test %>% mutate(condition2=ifelse(condition == "control", 0, ifelse(condition == "low", 1, 2)), condition2 = as.factor(condition2))
```

Then I ran the lmer model:

```
mod <- lmer(score ~ condition2 + (1|subject), data = test, REML = FALSE)
```

with the following output:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: score ~ condition2 + (1 | subject)
   Data: test

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   283.0    295.5   -136.5    273.0       85 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.09796 -0.51784  0.06943  0.64971  2.46609 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 subject  (Intercept) 0.2618   0.5116  
 Residual             1.0024   1.0012  
Number of obs: 90, groups:  subject, 30

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.4657     0.2053 82.8910  -2.268 0.025901 *  
condition21  -0.9316     0.2585 60.0000  -3.604 0.000638 ***
condition22  -0.8664     0.2585 60.0000  -3.352 0.001394 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Note that these coefficients are telling us about the mean difference between control and low (condition21) and control and high (condition22).

Now emmeans:

```
emmeans(mod, list(pairwise ~ condition2), adjust = "holm")
$`emmeans of condition2`
 condition2 emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 0          -0.466 0.209 85.8   -0.881  -0.0506
 1          -1.397 0.209 85.8   -1.812  -0.9822
 2          -1.332 0.209 85.8   -1.747  -0.9170

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$`pairwise differences of condition2`
 contrast estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 0 - 1      0.9316 0.263 62.1  3.543  0.0023 
 0 - 2      0.8664 0.263 62.1  3.295  0.0033 
 1 - 2     -0.0652 0.263 62.1 -0.248  0.8050
```

Notice how the 0-1 and 0-2 contrasts exactly match the output from lmer. This was not the case when comparing your lmer output to your emmeans output. What we get from emmeans is a direct test of the 1-2 contrast, which we did not get in lmer. The p-values are different, but not different enough that you would change your conclusion about statistical significance (i.e., if your alpha level is p<.05). I am not sure why they are different, but it has to do with the procedure difference in `lmertest` vs. `emmeans`.

Comment: Thank you, Erik! You reminded me of the problem of my contrast coding. Yes, now I realized the contrast coding I used is for orthogonal contrast (there is another error too but I corrected it), but I should have used the non-orthogonal contrast coding. I'll answer with the correct contrast coding.

Answer (score 1):

Now I realized the contrast coding in my question is for the orthogonal contrast. I should use the contrast coding for the non-orthogonal contrast. Here is the corrected contrast coding (assuming the condition levels are not changed):

```
# specify contrast weights
control_high <- c(-1/2, 1/2, 0)
control_low <- c(-1/2, 0, 1/2)
# create temporary matrix
mat.temp <- rbind(constant=1/3, control_high, control_low)
# get the inverse of that matrix
mat <- solve(mat.temp)
# drop the first column
mat <- mat[, -1]
# Now set the contrasts
contrasts(df$condition) <- mat
```

Now the summary() gives the following output that matches the significance test given in emmeans() and @Erik Ruzek's answer:

```
# Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
# Formula: score ~ condition + (1 | subject)
# Data: df
# 
# AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
# 283.0    295.5   -136.5    273.0       85 
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
# Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -3.09796 -0.51784  0.06943  0.64971  2.46609 
# 
# Random effects:
# Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
# subject  (Intercept) 0.2618   0.5116  
# Residual             1.0024   1.0012  
# Number of obs: 90, groups:  subject, 30
# 
# Fixed effects:
# Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)            -1.0650     0.1409 30.0000  -7.557    2e-08 ***
# conditioncontrol_high  -0.4332     0.1293 60.0000  -3.352 0.001394 ** 
# conditioncontrol_low   -0.4658     0.1293 60.0000  -3.604 0.000638 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
# (Intr) cndtncntrl_h
# cndtncntrl_h 0.000              
# cndtncntrl_l 0.000  0.500
```